# Polymer iron-ajax: bind component property to iron-ajax URL attribute?

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I would like to bind a component property value to the URL of my iron-ajax component.

My scenario looks like this...

I have an 'iron-meta' component which I use to store all of my API endpoints like so...

```
<iron-meta id="services" key="services" value=
    '{
            "baseApiUrl": {
              "foo":"/api/{dynamic_id}",
              "bar":"/api/{dynamic_id}/stuff"
            }
      }'>
</iron-meta>
```

I then import this meta object into the custom component that requires this endpoint for an iron-ajax and bind the value of this meta object to a "services" property in my custom component, like so...

```
<iron-meta-query id="query" key="services" value="{{services}}"></iron-meta-query>
```

For me to use a "services" endpoint that requires a component property value currently I need to access the iron-ajax by id and do a string replace on the API string to replace it with my component property value, like so...

```
_computeUrl: function(services,dynamic_id) {
    return this.services.baseApiUrl.bar.replace("{dynamic_id}", dynamic_id);
  }
```

I would like to directly bind my custom components' "dynamic_id" property to the imported "[[services.baseApiUrl.bar]]" value so that the below sample...

```
<iron-meta-query id="query" key="services" value="{{services}}"></iron-meta-query>

    <iron-ajax id="getHomeData"
        auto
        handle-as="json"
        content-type="application/json"
        url$="[[services.baseApiUrl.bar]]"
        method="GET"
        last-response="{{_response}}">
    </iron-ajax>

//dynamic_id = 1234;
```

...would resolve the iron-ajax URL to look like this...

```
"/api/1234/stuff"
```

without having to do any string replace on the imported service URL.

My question is, is there a polymer way to do this, if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Where is `dynamic_id` stored?

Comment: This could be anything, a sessionID, a route param, it doesn't really matter for the sake of this example. For this example it is just a property set inside the component that is calling `_computeUrl `

Comment: I can only think of two ways in which you can do it. One is what you are already using, other can be `computed properties`

Comment: Thanks a12626 I think for now I will create a behavior that can be shared between components which will handle the string replace, its still not the perfect solution but at least the solution will be re-usable for this functionality.